# Axis2 on Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, service, apache-axis

I recently began doing some work with Axis2 on a local Tomcat server.  Everything was going well, I hibernated my computer over the weekend.  When I started work this morning, I was obtaining an internal server error when I attempted to check my services.  When performing a validation check, I obtained the following error:

Examining Version Service

There was a problem in Axis2 version service , may be the service not available or some thing has gone wrong. But this does not mean system is not working ! Try to upload some other service and check to see whether it is working.

Any ideas how to solve this?  A restart of my PC didn't help and I haven't encountered this problem before.

Answer (score 0):

Seemed an reinstall of Tomcat did the trick.

For anyone else with this same problem:

1. Uninstall Tomcat from Add/Remove Programs in control panel
2. Delete the Tomcat/Apache folder
3. Reinstall Tomcat
4. Place the axis2.war file back into Tomcat

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete **axis2.war and the axis2 directory** from the webapp folder of the tomact when tomcat is stopped. Then start tomcat and see that axis2 is removed successfully. After that put axis2.war again to webapp directory. It will work.